# Concurrency issues with Model.get_or_create() and table locking in a Django/MySQL application

Tags: python, mysql, django, multithreading

I have spent the last few days struggling to eliminate a race condition from a Django application. The issue stems from the fact that I have several models on which I cannot enforce uniqueness at the database level, for various reasons, but I nevertheless want to ensure that there is only one instance of certain models with certain attribute values. In an attempt to do so, I came up with the following Manager and QuerySet subclasses (I'm leaving out some utility method definitions for brevity):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import logging, os
from contextlib import contextmanager
from django.db import (models, connections, router, transaction,
    IntegrityError, NotSupportedError, ProgrammingError)
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class LockingQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    """
    This is a custom QuerySet class to implement the actual get_or_create
    logic.
    """
    def get_or_create(self, defaults=None, **kwargs):
        lookup, params = self._extract_model_params(defaults, **kwargs)
        # Note that what I really want to do here is self.get(**lookup), and
        # catch any DoesNotExist exception that may occur
        qs = self.filter(**lookup)
        try:
            return qs[0], False
        except IndexError:
            return self.create(**params), True

class LockingManager(models.Manager):
    _active_locks = {}

    @contextmanager
    def lock(self):
        """
        Context manager that acquires a database lock and yields the name of
        the database on which the lock is active.
        """
        # Ensures that the database back end is MySQL and that the database
        # router returns the same database instance for writing to all the
        # tables that will need to be locked
        self._validate()
        using_dbname = router.db_for_write(self.model)
        if using_dbname in self._active_locks:
            yield using_dbname
            return
        # We can't obtain a lock if we're in an atomic block already. In this
        # case there's nothing we can really do but hope that the transaction
        # takes care of any race conditions.
        if connections[using_dbname].in_atomic_block:
            logger.warning(
                'Could not obtain write lock on %s because an atomic block is active.' % ', '.join(self._table_list)
            )
            yield using_dbname
            return
        autocommit_state = transaction.get_autocommit(using=using_dbname)
        transaction.set_autocommit(False, using=using_dbname)
        logger.debug('Unset autocommit for database "%s"' % using_dbname)
        cursor = connections[using_dbname].cursor()
        # self._table_list is a cached property that lists the tables that
        # need to be locked in order to do a get_or_create() for this model.
        cursor.execute(
            'LOCK TABLES %s' % ', '.join(['%s WRITE' % table for table in self._table_list])
        )
        self._active_locks[using_dbname] = True
        logger.debug('Locked tables %s for thread %s on process %s' % (
            ', '.join(self._table_list), connections[using_dbname]._thread_ident, os.getpid())
        )
        try:
            yield using_dbname
        finally:
            transaction.commit()
            del self._active_locks[using_dbname]
            cursor.execute('UNLOCK TABLES')
            logger.debug('Unlocked tables for thread %s on process %s' % (
                connections[using_dbname]._thread_ident, os.getpid()
            ))
            cursor.close()
            transaction.set_autocommit(autocommit_state, using=using_dbname)
            logger.debug('Reset autocommit for database "%s"' % using_dbname)

    def get_or_create(self, defaults=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Manager method to obtain write locks on all tables for this model and
        any related models before attempting the database operation.
        """
        with self.lock() as dbname:
            return self.using(dbname).get_or_create(defaults, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return LockingQuerySet(self.model, using=self.db)
```

Even with the issuing of the locks, I've still seen occasional duplicate insertions when testing under load (this code is running under Apache with mod_wsgi in daemon mode). I found this in my log:

```
2015-03-13 11:24:47,842: Unset autocommit for database "default"
2015-03-13 11:24:47,843: Unset autocommit for database "default"
2015-03-13 11:24:47,845: Locked tables table_x, table_y for thread 140096497956608 on process 16819
2015-03-13 11:24:47,867: Locked tables table_x, table_y for thread 140096565098240 on process 16820
2015-03-13 11:24:47,868: Unlocked tables for thread 140096497956608 on process 16819
2015-03-13 11:24:47,870: Reset autocommit for database "default"
2015-03-13 11:24:47,873: Unlocked tables for thread 140096565098240 on process 16820
2015-03-13 11:24:47,875: Reset autocommit for database "default"
```

This doesn't make any sense to me because it suggests that process 16820 was able to acquire a write lock on table_x and table_y, even though process 16819 just did the same thing two hundredths of a second prior. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how to lock tables for writing in MySQL?